# Java, Hibernate,Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have 2 entities User and Status. I can load users list and can see its sql(log) in console

> (select this_.id as id0_0_,
>   this_.cl_point_id as cl2_0_0_,
>   this_.date_ll as date3_0_0_,
>   this_.date_reg as date4_0_0_,
>   this_.name as name0_0_,
>   this_.passw_salt as passw6_0_0_,
>   this_.status_id as status7_0_0_,
>   this_.passw as passw0_0_, this_.login
>   as login0_0_ from users this_)

. 
But when I load Status the list is empty and there is no sql(log) in console. I can't find where is the problem?

User.java

```
package tj.eskhata.pos.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements DomainObject {
 @Id
 private Long id; 

 @Column(name="name")
 private String fullname;

 @Column(name="cl_point_id")
 private Long clPointId;

 @Column(name="login")
 private String wiaUsername;

 @Column(name="passw")
 private String wiaPassword;

 @Column(name="status_id")
 private Long statusId;

 @Column(name="date_reg")
 private Date dateReg;

 @Column(name="date_ll")
 private Date dateLl;

 @Column(name="passw_salt")
 private String passwSalt;


  public User() {
  }

  public User(String username, String password, String fullname,
      boolean isAdmin) {
    this.id=Long.valueOf(1);
 this.wiaUsername = username;
    this.wiaPassword = password;
    this.fullname = fullname;    
  }

  public String getFullname() {
    return fullname;
  }

  public String getWiaPassword() {
    return wiaPassword;
  }

  public String getWiaUsername() {
    return wiaUsername;
  }

  public void setFullname(String fullname) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
  }

  public void setWiaPassword(String password) {
    this.wiaPassword = password;
  }

  public void setWiaUsername(String username) {
    this.wiaUsername = username;
  }

  public Long getId() {
  return id;
  }

  public Long getClPointId() {
     return clPointId;
  }
  public Long getStatusId() {
     return statusId;
  }
  public Date getDateReg() {
     return dateReg;
  }
  public Date getDateLl() {
     return dateReg;
  }
  public String getPasswSalt() {
     return passwSalt;
  }
  public void getClPointId(Long clPointId_) {
   this.clPointId=clPointId_;
  }
  public void setStatusId(Long statusId_) {
   this.statusId=statusId_;
  }
  public void setDateReg(Date dateReg_) {
   this.dateReg=dateReg_;
  }
  public void setDateLl(Date dateLl_) {
   this.dateLl=dateLl_;
  }
  public void setPasswSalt(String passwSalt_) {
   this.passwSalt=passwSalt_;
  }
  public boolean isAdmin() {
     return false;
  }
}
```

Status.java

```
package tj.eskhata.pos.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="status")
public class Status implements DomainObject {

 public Status() {  
 }
 public Status(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public Status(Long id, String code, String name, String fullName,
   String color) {
  this.id = id;
  this.code = code;
  this.name = name;
  this.fullName = fullName;
  this.color = color;
 }


 @Id
 private Long id; 
 public void setId( Long id_) {
  this.id=id_;
 }
 public Long getId() {
  return this.id;
 }


 @Column(name = "code")
 private String code;
 public void setCode( String code_) {
  this.code=code_;
 }
 public String getCode() {
  return this.code;
 }

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;
 public void setName( String name_) {
  this.name=name_;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return this.name;
 }

 @Column(name = "full_name")
 private String fullName;
 public void setFullName( String fullName_) {
  this.name=fullName_;
 }
 public String getFullName() {
  return this.fullName;
 }

 @Column(name = "color")
 private String color;
 public void setColor( String color_) {
  this.color=color_;
 }
 public String getColor() {
  return this.color;
 }
}
```

*

```
UserDaoImpl.java:
package tj.eskhata.pos.dao.hibernate;

import tj.eskhata.pos.dao.UserDao;
import tj.eskhata.pos.domain.User;

public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractHibernateDaoImpl<User>
    implements UserDao {

  public UserDaoImpl() {
    super(User.class);
  }
}

StatusDaoImpl.java:
package tj.eskhata.pos.dao.hibernate;

import tj.eskhata.pos.dao.StatusDao;
import tj.eskhata.pos.domain.Status;

public class StatusDaoImpl extends AbstractHibernateDaoImpl<Status>
    implements StatusDao {

  public StatusDaoImpl() {
    super(Status.class);
  }
}

UserDao.java:

package tj.eskhata.pos.dao;

import tj.eskhata.pos.domain.User;

public interface UserDao extends Dao<User> {

}

StatusDao.java:
package tj.eskhata.pos.dao;

import tj.eskhata.pos.domain.Status;

public interface StatusDao extends Dao<Status> {

}
```

AbstractHibernateDaoImpl.java:

```
package tj.eskhata.pos.dao.hibernate;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projections;

import tj.eskhata.pos.dao.Dao;
import tj.eskhata.pos.domain.DomainObject;

public abstract class AbstractHibernateDaoImpl<T extends DomainObject>
    implements Dao<T> {

  private Class<T> domainClass;

  private SessionFactory sf;

  public AbstractHibernateDaoImpl(Class<T> domainClass) {
    this.domainClass = domainClass;
  }

  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sf;
  }

  public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
    this.sf = sf;
  }

  public void delete(T object) {
    getSession().delete(object);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public T load(long id) {
    return (T) getSession().get(domainClass, id);
  }

  public void save(T object) {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(object);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<T> findAll() {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(domainClass);
    List<T> r=(List<T>) criteria.list();
    return r;
  }

  public int countAll() {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(domainClass);
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
    return (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult();
  }

  public Session getSession() {
    // presumes a current session, which we have through the
    // OpenSessionInViewFilter; doesn't work without that
    return sf.getCurrentSession();
  }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:jndi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi/spring-jndi.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd"> 

 <bean id="placeholderConfig"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
   <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
  </property>
  <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
   <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass">
   <value>${jdbc.driver}</value>
  </property>
  <property name="jdbcUrl">
   <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
  </property>
  <property name="user">
   <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
  </property>
  <property name="password">
   <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
  </property>
  <property name="minPoolSize">
   <value>${c3p0.minPoolSize}</value>
  </property>
  <property name="maxPoolSize">
   <value>${c3p0.maxPoolSize}</value>
  </property>
  <property name="checkoutTimeout">
   <value>20000</value>
  </property>
  <property name="maxIdleTime">
   <value>${c3p0.maxIdleTime}</value>
  </property>
  <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">
   <value>${c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod}</value>
  </property>
  <property name="automaticTestTable">
   <value>${c3p0.automaticTestTable}</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>tj.eskhata.pos.domain.User</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager"
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>
 <tx:annotation-driven />

 <bean id="wicketApplication"
  class="tj.eskhata.pos.PosApplication">
 </bean>

 <bean id="UserDao"
  class="tj.eskhata.pos.dao.hibernate.UserDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="CountryDao"
  class="tj.eskhata.pos.dao.hibernate.CountryDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="StatusDao"
  class="tj.eskhata.pos.dao.hibernate.StatusDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="GenericDao"
  class="tj.eskhata.pos.dao.hibernate.GenericDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="DiscountsService" class="tj.eskhata.pos.services.DiscountsServiceImpl"> 
  <property name="userDao" ref="UserDao" />
  <property name="countryDao" ref="CountryDao" />
  <property name="statusDao" ref="StatusDao" />
  <property name="genericDao" ref="GenericDao" />
 </bean> 

</beans>
```

DiscountService:

```
package tj.eskhata.pos.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import tj.eskhata.pos.domain.Country;
import tj.eskhata.pos.domain.Status;
import tj.eskhata.pos.domain.User;

public interface DiscountsService {

  <T> T load(Class<T> type, long id);  

  List<User> findAllUsers();
  void saveUser(User user);
  void deleteUser(User user);

  List<Country> findAllCountries();
  void saveCountry(Country country);
  void deleteCountry(Country country);

  List<Status> findAllStatuses();
  void saveStatus(Status status);
  void deleteStatus(Status status);
}


package tj.eskhata.pos.services;

import java.util.List;

import tj.eskhata.pos.dao.CountryDao;
import tj.eskhata.pos.dao.GenericDao;
import tj.eskhata.pos.dao.StatusDao;
import tj.eskhata.pos.dao.UserDao;
import tj.eskhata.pos.domain.Country;
import tj.eskhata.pos.domain.Status;
import tj.eskhata.pos.domain.User;

public class DiscountsServiceImpl implements DiscountsService {

  private UserDao userDao;
  private CountryDao countryDao;
  private StatusDao statusDao;
  private GenericDao genericDao;

  public DiscountsServiceImpl() {
  }

  public <T> T load(Class<T> type, long id) {
    return genericDao.load(type, id);
  }

  public List<User> findAllUsers() {
    return userDao.findAll();
  }
  public void saveUser(User user) {
        userDao.save(user);
  }  
  public void deleteUser(User user) {
       userDao.delete(user);
  }
  public UserDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
  }
  public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
       this.userDao = userDao;
  }

  public List<Country> findAllCountries() {
        return countryDao.findAll();
      }
  public void saveCountry(Country country) {
      countryDao.save(country);
  }  
  public void deleteCountry(Country country) {
      countryDao.delete(country);
  }
  public CountryDao getCountryDao() {
       return countryDao;
  }
  public void setCountryDao(CountryDao countryDao) {
       this.countryDao = countryDao;
  }

  public List<Status> findAllStatuses() {
        return statusDao.findAll();
      }
  public void saveStatus(Status status) {
        statusDao.save(status);
  }  
  public void deleteStatus(Status status) {
        statusDao.delete(status);
  }
  public StatusDao getStatusDao() {
        return statusDao;
  }
  public void setStatusDao(StatusDao statusDao) {
        this.statusDao = statusDao;
  }

  public GenericDao getGenericDao() {
    return genericDao;
  }
  public void setGenericDao(GenericDao genericDao) {
    this.genericDao = genericDao;
  }

}
```

Comment: Your domain objects all seem sensible. Can you show us the code you are executing to persist and retrieve?

Comment: Example or retrieving

@SpringBean

private DiscountsService service;

service.findAllStatuses().size();

Answer (score 7):

The `Status` entity looks fine (it has an `@Entity` annotation, it has a default no-arg constructor, it has an `@Id`), I can't spot anything obvious.

So I would:

- double check the startup logs to check for any complaint.
- use the Hibernate Console (if you are using Eclipse) or any equivalent to load the `Status` using raw HQL or Criteria.
- write a unit test anyway.

Oh, by the way, this is unrelated but you shouldn't have such things in your `User` entity:

```
@Column(name="status_id")
private Long statusId;
```

These `Long` look like foreign keys. When using an ORM, you should have objects and associations between objects, not ids. Something like this:

```
@ManyToOne
private Status status;
```

Same remark for `clPointId`.

You are IMHO thinking "too relational" and "not enough object". I might be wrong but having foreign key attributes in an entity is a strong hint.

---

> I have changed @Column(name="status_id") private Long statusId; to @ManyToOne private Status status; Now I receiving the ERROR: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on tj.eskhata.pos.domain.User.status references an unknown entity: tj.eskhata.pos.domain.Status

This message clearly shows that something goes wrong with `Status` that isn't recognized as an Entity (and thus can't be referenced in an association, preventing the session factory from being instantiated). This is usually due to a configuration or mapping problem. So:

- Do you declare entities somewhere (in `hibernate.cfg.xml` or in `persistence.xml`)? If yes, did you declare `Status`? If you are using classpath scanning, is `Status` scanned?
- Double-check the mapping, check that the column names really exist (it's unclear if you are using an existing physical model).
- Activate logging (Spring Logging, [Hibernate Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)), this is helpful during development and will help to find the problem.

Comment: I have changed 
@Column(name="status_id")
private Long statusId;
to 
@ManyToOne
private Status status;
Now I receiving the ERROR:
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on tj.eskhata.pos.domain.User.status references an unknown entity: tj.eskhata.pos.domain.Status

Comment: You were right. The issue wwas in applicationContext.xml. I have missed to add Status as entity:

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>tj.eskhata.pos.domain.User</value>
   </list>
  </property>


Thank's a lot for help!